# how to insert php calendar in my php page

Tags: php, codeigniter

i want to insert php calendar to my page ..
 which is the best way to do it

Comment: what do you mean by a calendar? a js calendar for entering dates or a google like calendar??

Comment: April 2010
Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat

  1 2 3

4 5 6 7 8 9 10

11 12 13 14 15 16 17

18 19 20 21 22 23 24

25 26 27 28 29 30  

I want to display the calendar like this in php is there any function to inclue calendar like this

Comment: Thanks for asking this question, this shed new lights to calender library in CI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it makes your life easier, [you can embed a Google calendar](http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=41207).

--EDIT--
Well, according to the tags on the post - which i only noticed now - your question is about how to add a calendar using CodeIgnniter.
[Here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/calendar.html):

```
$this->load->library('calendar');

echo $this->calendar->generate();
```

Answer (score 1):

the faster way is, if you have linux server, by calling:

```
<?php
exec("/usr/bin/cal -h", $buff);
echo "<pre>".implode("\n", $buff)."</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: Brilliant idea ..!! most of the time this comes hand , unless you need more events associated with dates, like a date-picker or a full calender

Answer (score 1):

using this function i can calculated the first day of the month and last date of the month and filed the date with these parameters

```
function phpcal()
    {
        //$month=05;
        //$day=01;
        $cur_date = date('d-m-Y');
        list($day,$month,$year) = explode("-", $cur_date);



        //$year=2014;
         //$month = $this->input->post('monthnum');
        // $year = $this->input->post('yrnum');
         $zeroCnt = date("w", mktime(0,0,0,$month,$day,$year)); 
         $lastDay = date("t", strtotime($year . "-" . $month . "-01"));
        $tempArr = array('0'=>'January','1'=>'February','2'=>"March", '3'=>"April",'4'=>"May",'5'=>"June",'6'=>"July",
        '7'=>"August",'8'=>"September",'9'=>"October",'10'=>"November",'11'=>"December");
        if( (!empty($month)) && (!empty($year)) )
        {
            $cal[0] = $month+1;
            $cal[1] = $year;
            //$cal[2] = $tempArr[$month-1];
            $month-1;
            $data['cal'] = $cal;
        }
        // "March", "April","May","June","July","August","September","November","December"];
        for($i=0;$i<$zeroCnt;$i++)
        {
            $dateArr[$i] = 0;
        }

        for($j=1,$i=$zeroCnt;$j<=$lastDay;$i++,$j++)
        {
            $dateArr[$i] = $j ;         
        }
        $data['zeroCnt'] = $zeroCnt;
        $data['lastDay'] = $lastDay;
        $data['dateArr'] = $dateArr;
        $data['month'] = $month;
        $data['year'] = $year;

        $this->load->view('phpcal',$data);


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to a datepicker like [jQuery's Datepicker](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker)?

Answer (score 0):

**Calendaring Class**

The Calendar class enables you to dynamically create calendars. Your calendars can be formatted through the use of a calendar template, allowing 100% control over every aspect of its design. In addition, you can pass data to your calendar cells.

Initializing the Class
Like most other classes in CodeIgniter, the Calendar class is initialized in your controller using the `$this->load->library` function:

```
$this->load->library('calendar');
```

Once loaded, the Calendar object will be available using: $this->calendar

**Displaying a Calendar**

Here is a very simple example showing how you can display a calendar:

```
$this->load->library('calendar');

echo $this->calendar->generate();
```

The above code will generate a calendar for the current month/year based on your server time. To show a calendar for a specific month and year you will pass this information to the calendar generating function:

```
$this->load->library('calendar');

echo $this->calendar->generate(2006, 6);
```

The above code will generate a calendar showing the month of June in 2006. The first parameter specifies the year, the second parameter specifies the month.

**Passing Data to your Calendar Cells**

To add data to your calendar cells involves creating an associative array in which the keys correspond to the days you wish to populate and the array value contains the data. The array is passed to the third parameter of the calendar generating function. Consider this example:

```
$this->load->library('calendar');

$data = array(
               3  => 'http://example.com/news/article/2006/03/',
               7  => 'http://example.com/news/article/2006/07/',
               13 => 'http://example.com/news/article/2006/13/',
               26 => 'http://example.com/news/article/2006/26/'
             );

echo $this->calendar->generate(2006, 6, $data);
```

Using the above example, day numbers 3, 7, 13, and 26 will become links pointing to the URLs you've provided.

**Note:** By default it is assumed that your array will contain links. In the section that explains the calendar template below, you'll see how you can customize how data passed to your cells is handled so you can pass different types of information.

**Setting Display Preferences**

There are seven preferences you can set to control various aspects of the calendar. Preferences are set by passing an array of preferences in the second parameter of the loading function. Here is an example:

```
$prefs = array (
               'start_day'    => 'saturday',
               'month_type'   => 'long',
               'day_type'     => 'short'
             );

$this->load->library('calendar', $prefs);

echo $this->calendar->generate();
```

The above code would start the calendar on Saturday, use the "long" month heading, and the "short" day names. More information regarding preferences below.

**Showing Next/Previous Month Links**
To allow your calendar to dynamically increment/decrement via the next/previous links requires that you set up your calendar code similar to this example:

```
    $prefs = array (
                   'show_next_prev'  => TRUE,
                   'next_prev_url'   => 'http://example.com/index.php/calendar/show/'
                 );

    $this->load->library('calendar', $prefs);

echo $this->calendar->generate($this->uri->segment(3), $this->uri->segment(4));
```

You'll notice a few things about the above example:

You must set the `"show_next_prev"` to TRUE.
You must supply the URL to the controller containing your calendar in the "next_prev_url" preference.
You must supply the "year" and "month" to the calendar generating function via the URI segments where they appear (Note: The calendar class automatically adds the year/month to the base URL you provide.).
Creating a Calendar Template
By creating a calendar template you have 100% control over the design of your calendar. Each component of your calendar will be placed within a pair of pseudo-variables as shown here:

```
$prefs['template'] = '

   {table_open}<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">{/table_open}

   {heading_row_start}<tr>{/heading_row_start}

   {heading_previous_cell}<th><a href="{previous_url}">&lt;&lt;</a></th>{/heading_previous_cell}
   {heading_title_cell}<th colspan="{colspan}">{heading}</th>{/heading_title_cell}
   {heading_next_cell}<th><a href="{next_url}">&gt;&gt;</a></th>{/heading_next_cell}

   {heading_row_end}</tr>{/heading_row_end}

   {week_row_start}<tr>{/week_row_start}
   {week_day_cell}<td>{week_day}</td>{/week_day_cell}
   {week_row_end}</tr>{/week_row_end}

   {cal_row_start}<tr>{/cal_row_start}
   {cal_cell_start}<td>{/cal_cell_start}

   {cal_cell_content}<a href="{content}">{day}</a>{/cal_cell_content}
   {cal_cell_content_today}<div class="highlight"><a href="{content}">{day}</a></div>{/cal_cell_content_today}

   {cal_cell_no_content}{day}{/cal_cell_no_content}
   {cal_cell_no_content_today}<div class="highlight">{day}</div>{/cal_cell_no_content_today}

   {cal_cell_blank}&nbsp;{/cal_cell_blank}

   {cal_cell_end}</td>{/cal_cell_end}
   {cal_row_end}</tr>{/cal_row_end}

   {table_close}</table>{/table_close}
';

$this->load->library('calendar', $prefs);

echo $this->calendar->generate();
```